# not able to execute mongdb aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to `sum` certain field value in my `mongo` document using `aggregate` function. But I am getting 0 as sum value.

Below is my sample mongo document:

```
 {
    _id: ObjectId("64d9e5e7f7b6237202be444b"),
    userName: 'merch2@mail.com',
    remoteAccessToken: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY5MTYxMTczNCwiZXhwIjoxNjkxNjEyMzM0fQ.PkIyyetG739jTQPzmypsbF8oTCrBzYLe5bWbKj38vjA',
    requestPayload: { amount: 90, msisdn: '9816762561', transactionId: 41657 },
    response: {
      code: 200,
      data: {
        message: 'Payment success'
      },
      error: null
    },
    createdOn: ISODate("2023-08-14T08:29:27.572Z"),
    _class: 'com.atlas.xorx.domain.PaymentLogDetail'
  }
```

*What I am trying to achieve*

I want sum of `requestPayload.amount` of all successful payments i.e. with `response.code:200` of certain `userName`

*I am trying below aggregate query:*

```
db.paymentLogDetail.aggregate([{"$match":{"$and" : [{"userName" : "merch2@mail.com"},{"response.code":200 }]}},{"$group":{"_id":null,"total":{"$sum":"requestPayload.amount"}}}]);
```

*I am receiving below response:*

```
[ { _id: null, total: 0 } ]
```

What changes do I have to make in my existing query in order to get valid sum of success payment amounts of any username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response came as expected. Its only a single character issue. The value we want to `sum` (or any other `aggregate` function) has to be appended with `$`. So correct query is :

```
 db.paymentLogDetail.aggregate([{"$match":{"$and" : [{"userName" : "merch2@mail.com"},{"response.code":200 }]}},{"$group":{"_id":null,"total":{"$sum":"$requestPayload.amount"}}}]);
```

Its `"$requestPayload.amount"` and NOT `"requestPayload.amount"`